# Python class variable dictionary in class S updated from class U is not seen by class E

Tags: python-3.8, class-variables

I have a dictionary as a class variable. The vsw.VswInformation is a simple data class containing mostly strings. There is a class method that adds vsw.VswInformation elements to this dictionary, and another class method that gets this dictionary.

The class is as follows:

```
class Swc:
    lock: Lock = Lock()
    vsw_infos: Dict[str, vsw.VswInformation] = dict()
   
    def __init__(self):
        # This is a loopback server
        self.exchange_module: exchange.ExchangeModule = exchange.ExchangeModule()
             
    @classmethod
    def add_vsw_info(cls, vsw_info: vsw.VswInformation):
        # Adds elements to the class dictionary
        with Swc.lock:
            if vsw_info.serial_number == None:
                raise SwcException('Needed input parameters in the VSW Information was missing')
            key: str = vsw_info.serial_number
            Swc.vsw_infos[key] = vsw_info
            
    @classmethod
    def get_vsw_entries(cls) -> Dict[str, vsw.VswInformation]:
        # Gets the class dictionary
        with Swc.lock:
            return Swc.vsw_infos
```

In a unittest I instantiate the Swc object and then I create two vsw.VswInformation objects and call the Swc class method to add them to the class variable. The unittest sends a GET request to the loopback server, and the loopback server calls the Swc class method to get the class dictionary. However, it is empty.

While stepping through the debugger, I step into the two class methods that add the item and see that the class dictionary is updated as expected. However, when I call the class method to get the dictionary in the server, the dictionary is empty. It is as if this line:

```
vsw_infos: Dict[str, vsw.VswInformation] = dict()
```

is called every time I call the method to get the dictionary in the server (not so if I call the method in the unittest).

So I tried initializing the dictionary in the `__init__()` method instead but that gave the same result. What am I doing wrong? Better yet, what is wrong with my thinking? Isn't this class dictionary like a global variable and passed by reference? Do I need a global (the lock seems to works and it's not a global).

Here is the unittest:

```
    def test_get_all_vsw_infos_from_swc(self):
        swc_main: Swc = Swc()
        # Create two vsw_info entries
        Swc.add_vsw_info(self.create_vsw_info('1234rr'))
        Swc.add_vsw_info(self.create_vsw_info('1234ss'))

        connection: http.client.HTTPConnection = http.client.HTTPConnection("localhost", 9090)
        connection.request("GET", "/watches/")
        # The test fails here because of the empty dictionary
        response: http.client.HTTPResponse = connection.getresponse()
        ...
```

The GET request handler in the server is as follows:

```
    def do_GET(self):
        print(f"GET request received. Path: {self.path}")
        cmd_index: int = self.path.find("watches/")
        response_code: int = 200
        if cmd_index >= 0:
            json_bytes: bytes = None
            # This is empty but I expected two entries
            dicts = swc.Swc.get_vsw_entries()
            ...
```

There must be SOME post that addresses this issue but I could not find one in spite of the HUGE list of similarities provided by SO.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem - I was running the server as a Python Process and not a Python Thread. The reason I was running it as a Process was because I could find no way to stop serve_forever() as a Thread. As a Process one can call terminate().

Going back to a Thread, I replaced the 'serve_forever' with handle_request() in a while loop:

```
    def start_server(self):
        print("HTTP Server started")
        while self.keep_running:
            self.exchange_server.handle_request()
        print("Server thread stopped")
```

The problem here is that the handle_request() is blocking so in my shutdown method I had to invoke a client to send a useless GET request and that released the thread

```
    def close_exchange_module(self):
        if self.isRunning:
            # Release the while loop
            self.keep_running = False
            # 'unblock' the handle_request()
            connection: HTTPConnection = HTTPConnection("localhost", 9090)
            connection.request("GET", "/")
            connection.close()
            self.exchange_thread.join()
            self.exchange_server.server_close()
            self.is_running = False
        print("Server stopped.")
```